# Overwriting CSS value in different pages

Tags: css, html

I have the following CSS which is used for horizontal scrolling of images placed side by side in a div. As advised by @Moob I am using

```
#scroll li:first-child {
padding-left:30px;
}
#scroll li:last-child {
padding-right:50px;
}
```

from the following css

```
#scroll {
width:665px;
height:550px;
margin:0px auto;
background:#ffffff;
overflow-y:hidden

}
#scroll ul {
margin:0; 
padding:0;
display:table;
list-style:none;
}
#scroll li {
padding:10px 100px;
text-align:center;
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
border:1px solid #fff;
}

#scroll li:first-child {
padding-left:30px;
}
#scroll li:last-child {
padding-right:50px;
}

#scroll img {
border:0;
display:block;
margin:0px auto;
}

#scroll span {
padding:10px 0 0;
display:block;

}
```

In order to control the left padding of the first image and the right padding of the last image since the images are of varying length/height not great than 665 by 550 px. and I am showing the images in a frame type box with horizontal scrolling enabled. My question is if I want to use the same CSS on 5 different pages to show different types of images, how can I individually set the

```
#scroll li:first-child {
padding-left:30px;
}
#scroll li:last-child {
padding-right:50px;
}
```

for each page, since the padding would be different on different pages for the first and last images? Do I just add it in the head style of that page under my css file link? will it overwrite the file value?

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: Yes. As long as the page-specific css comes later than the generic site-wide css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't add page specific CSS to your page headers, it is a nightmare to maintain.

Add a unique `id` to your `body` tag on each page:

```
<body id="page1">
```

Then use that `id` as a selector in your CSS to overide your original settings:

```
#page1 #scroll li:first-child {
   padding-left:30px;
}
#page1 #scroll li:last-child {
   padding-right:50px;
}

#page2 #scroll li:first-child {
   padding-left:40px;
}
#page2 #scroll li:last-child {
   padding-right:60px;
}

...

#page9 #scroll li:first-child {
   padding-left:50px;
}
#page9 #scroll li:last-child {
   padding-right:70px;
}
```

This way you keep all of your CSS in one file.

Comment: Actually (in this case) it wouldn't because you have an extra # selector making the page overrides more specific than the original. But you make a valid point.

Comment: Thanks! This worked like a charm. and in the process learned something new :)

Comment: that's the best thing about SO. You learn something new everyday :)

Answer (score 1):

As long as your in-page styling code comes after the inclusion of your css file, it will take priority. Simply import your css file, then following this include adjustments in a  tag, as CSS prioritized on the last rule mentioned.